# TRIM not works with lines and tabs of a xpath in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, xpath

With this query

```
SELECT trim(title) FROM (
  SELECT
    unnest( xpath('//p[@class="secTitle1"]', xmlText )::varchar[] ) AS title
  FROM t1 
) as t2
```

and XML input text with lines and spaces,

```
  <root>
  ...
  <p class="x">

         text text
         text text
  </p><p> ...</p>
  ...
  </root>
```

The `trim()` have no effect (!). It is a PostgreSQL bug? How to apply `fn:normalize-space()` with the XPath? I need something like "WHERE title is not null"? (Oracle is simpler...) How to do this simple query with PostreSQL?

### Workaround

I need a well-configured build-in function, not a workaround... But I need to work and to show results, so I am using regular expression...

```
    SELECT id, TRIM(regexp_replace(tit, E'[\\n\\r\\t ]+', ' ', 'g')) AS tit
    FROM (
        SELECT 
          id, -- xpath returns array of 1, 2, or more strings
          unnest( xpath('//p[@class="secTitle1"]', texto )::VARCHAR[] ) AS tit
        FROM t
    ) AS tmp
```

So, a "only simple space trim" is not friendly, not util (!).

**EDIT after @mu comment**

I try

```
    SELECT id, TRIM(tit, E'\\n\\r\\t') AS tit
```

and

```
    SELECT id, TRIM(tit, '\n\r\t') AS tit
```

both NOT WORKs.

---

### QUESTION REMAINS:

1. there are no TRIM-option or postgresql configuration to say to TRIM work as it is required?
2. can I use `normalize-space()` at xpath? How?
3. I am using PostgreSQL 9.1, need to upgrade?

Comment: trim: ["Remove the longest string containing only the characters (a space by default) from the start/end/both ends of the string"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL). So you can specify what should be trimmed, you could also do a single `regexp_replace(..., E'^\\s*(.*?)\\s*$', E'\\1')` instead of `trim`. I don't know enough about PostgreSQL's XML stuff to say any more.

Comment: Hum, I am trying to configure TRIM with a second parameter... No,  `trim(tit,E'\\n\\r\\t ')` not works as `regexp_replace(tit, E'[\\n\\r\\t ]+', ' ', 'g')`. Not works... About use of regex, it is a workaround, I edited the question to be emphatic that need a trim function or a better PostgreSQL version.

Comment: Have you read the `trim` documentation that I linked to?

Comment: Yes, I am simplying the "regex for trim", because not affect the question (why TRIM not detect all types of spaces?!)... And have you read my (edited) section "Workaround" above?

Answer (score 1):

It works in 9.2, and it works on 8.4 too.

```
postgres=# select trim(unnest(string_to_array(e'\t\tHello\n\t\tHello\n\t\tHello', e'\n')), e'\t');
 btrim 
-------
 Hello
 Hello
 Hello
(3 rows)
```

your regexp replace any char \n or \r or \t, but trim working with string "\n\r\t". It has different meaning than you expect.

Comment: PS: a question for the PostgreSQL team is "why TRIM is not friendly with a default "all kind of spaces" like another languages, it is a standard?

Comment: Thanks about `trim(x,e'\t ')`, with correct escape string (!). A simulation is more near to `select trim(unnest(string_to_array(e'\t \t Hello1 |\n x\t\t| \r\n \n\r Hello2\n\t\tHello3', '|')), e'\t\n\r ')`... Ok, it runs with your array, but **not works with my XPath**...

Comment: @PeterKrauss I am think, so it was designed in different era - nobody expected, so databases will process documents with tabs. But it is in standard http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#functions-TRIM

Comment: @PavelStelule, good link showing another answer ("only space by default" is a standard), thanks.  About the point of the main question, I not understand (it is a PostgreSQL-BUG?!) why `TRIM(regexp_replace(X, E'[\\n\\r\\t ]+', ' ', 'g'))` works and `TRIM(X, E'\n\r\t ')` not works.

Comment: @PeterKrauss - regexp replace any char \n or \r or \t, but trim working with string "\n\r\t". It has different meaning than you expect.

Comment: Well, PostgreSQL have limitations... But you show the point, and it is an important answer (!): for a click to "accpeted answer" we need only a copy/paste to there.

Answer (score 1):

... **9 years later**, after question, following XML trends and the evolution of PostgreSQL.

  (this is a WIKI please edit!)

### General solution for XML in PostgreSQL in 2023 (and before)

Use the XML data type **for basic storage only**.
 For any other application, **transform your XML into JSONb**.

XML and JSON are "document models", they are interchangeable (you can transform). But, it's a developer choice, only JSONb evolved:
[all handling functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) have been implemented in JSONb in this last decade.

Here an example of the same XML-thing in JSONB, it works fine and meets your intuition!

```sql
SELECT 'line'||ROW_NUMBER() over(),
       trim(obj->>'p',E'\n\r\t ') with_trim,
       obj->>'p' AS no_trim
FROM jsonb_path_query(
  '[{"x":1,"p":"  text1  text2   "},{"y":2,"p":"\t\ntext3 text4 \n \n "}]',
  '$[*]'
) t(obj);
```

|  | with_trim | no_trim |
| --- | --- | --- |
| effect | trim removes all | all lines and spaces stay there |
| result line1 | `text1 text2` | `text1 text2` |
| result line2 | `text3 text4` | `\t\ntext3 text4 \n \n` |

PS: for JSONb-numerical values, like `obj->'x'`, the most efficient is to cast it directly by `(obj->'x')::int`.  The operator `->>` transforms JSONb-string into SQL-text: all SQL-text functions works with it as expected, **no surprises**.

### PostgreSQL team abandoned XML

XML handling was born with XPath v1 in 1999; and evolved with XPath 2.0 in 2007, then XPath 3.0 in 2014, and XPath 3.1 in 2017...

However, **XPath 1.0** is still, since 2000's, the only version that is available in all PostgreSQL versions.

---

Note about W3C perspective. [No official news](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) for 2023 or future. Stops with XPath v3, because it is so complex and **only a few niche applications actually need it**.